# Drawing boundaries on a map with LeafletJS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm starting to play with code that can generate maps. I am now looking at OSM (OpenStreetMaps) as a great solution. Also LeafletJS makes it very easy to draw maps based on OSM. So far so good.

I would like to be able to draw an outline (boundary) of a county and am trying to understand how this process will look like. Do I first make a call to find coords and then pass them into Leaflet or is there a better way?

I can get boundaries using Nominatim API, but calling like this:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?state=tx&county=Lee
```

And I can draw area in Leaflet like this:

```
var polygon = L.polygon([
    [51.509, -0.08],
    [51.503, -0.06],
    [51.51, -0.047]
]).addTo(mymap);
```

So, am I overthinking or this is how it works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a single function to get the county geometry and add it to map. Try the following code:

```
function drawCountyBoundary(county, state)
{
    url = `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?county=${county}&state=${state}&polygon_geojson=1&format=jsonv2`
    fetch(url).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    geojsonFeature = json[0].geojson;
    L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);
  });
}

drawCountyBoundary('Lee', 'Tx')
```

Comment: Wow, this looks pretty great, thanks! I'm getting the following JS error and not sure why: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function

Comment: Also I've added map = L.map("mapCnty"); but still no luck.

Comment: Here's my failed attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/9ax2u0ty/

Comment: Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sodpe3km/6/).

Comment: That looks great, thanks. Since the state can be off the canvas for this view, I guess I can start with full state view, then add the county outline and then zoom-in and center. But this is a great start for sure!

Comment: Yes, you can set view to the center of the state. Assuming only Texas counties the view can be set as:`var map = L.map('map').setView([31.3913424,-99.1712139], 5);`

Comment: Yes, absolutely. There's something like .flyTo() in LeafletJS which will help with zoom. I think I'll need to figure out the viewBox of the county before firing that.